# Make Bootstrap modal adapt to text

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalMSJ" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight: bold; color:black;" id="exampleModalLabel">Documento</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;" id="MSJ">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The modal shows a message that is not always the same. And I show it on screen using JQUERY, like this:

```
$("#MSJ").html(Respuesta);
$("#ModalMSJ").modal("show");
```

and I want it to adapt itself to the message text.

this is how it looks currently when one of the messages are shown:

[image: Error]

How can I make the modal adapt to message text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add `style=" width: auto; height:auto !important;"` to the `div class="modal-dialog"`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalMSJ" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style=" width: auto; height:auto !important;" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight: bold; color:black;" id="exampleModalLabel">Documento</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;" id="MSJ">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```